# Undefined variable record

Tags: php

I get the following PHP error: `undefined variable record`.

Please advise what I am doing wrong as I am new to PHP. This is part of my code and below where I'm getting the error.

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
  $record = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * from accounts WHERE  id = '$_GET[id]'"));
  foreach($record as $key=>$val) $record[$key] = stripslashes($val);
}

<tr>
  <td width="28%"><div align="right">Name</div></td>
  <td width="72%"><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $record['name'] ?>"/></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your table you call `<?php echo $record['name'] ?>`, but `$record` is only set inside your if-statement. Meaning, if your if-statement is not true, it will be skipped and $record will never be set.

A simple fix would be to add an else clause to catch situations where no id was set.

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $record = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * from accounts WHERE  id = '$_GET[id]'"));
    foreach($record as $key=>$val) $record[$key] = stripslashes($val);
} else {
    // No id set, set an empty record
    $record = array('name' => null);
}
```

Comment: if i implement your suggestion i get undefined record with the rest of code</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="localpath"  value="<?php echo $record['localpath'] ?>"/> 
        </td>
    </tr>

Comment: Just another reason why you should always paste your *complete* code, no one is now aware of this. But you can just simply extend the "dummy" array with the keys that you need. Like `$record = array('name' => null, 'localpath' => null);` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are just accessing without the get variable id. Because of that, the variable $record is never initializated and the error prompts to your output.

You can fix it initializating it before the if statement or echo its values only if is set or not empty:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $record = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * from accounts WHERE  id = '$_GET[id]'"));
    foreach($record as $key=>$val) $record[$key] = stripslashes($val);
}

<tr>
  <td width="28%"><div align="right">Name</div></td>
  <td width="72%"><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo (!empty($record['name']))?$record['name']:""; ?>"/></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: if i implement your suggestion i get the following error:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'

Comment: Sorry, I forgot one )

Comment: @WaleedDonough seriosly, you should have tried to fix an error that is about `;`, otherwise you don't deserve help.

Comment: that code worked for most of my sections thanks alot. just 2 sections of code is different,please advise on this as well <?php if($record['copyperms'] == "Y") echo "checked"; ?>/> it gives the same undefined variable record error. thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok... but you must learn a bit of what you are doing. If not, you will need always my help and I'm not going to be here always or I'm not going to be willing to do your work. Your solution is: <?php if((!empty($record['copyperms'])) && $record['copyperms'] == "Y") echo "checked"; ?>

Comment: that worked thanks. I am extremely great full for your assistance. Its not due to a lack of trying. I'm new and still struggling. Thanks again